# Should one put the definite article before a date?

Tags: definite-article, dates

In the following examples, should the definite article "the" be present?

> This article will discuss all journal articles on the subject written between [**the**] 3rd December 2010 and [**the**] 20 January 2011.
>
> On [**the**] 6th May 2013, three men were selected for a special mission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only use "the" if you also put "of" between the date and the month:

- "...between the 3rd of December, 2010, and..."
- "On the 6th of May, 2013, three men..."

Also note the placement of the commas around the year, a [pretty strict standard](http://www.ncsu.edu/ncsu/grammar/Comma3.html) if you include the date. Of course, the European format doesn't take commas, or "the," or "of":

- "...between 3 December 2010 and..."
- "On 6 May 2013, three men..."

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge is we should put "the" while referring to the dates of the same month to make it clear and avoiding mentioning the month again.

Example: Today is July 3rd. See the following:

> 1. I will travel to Albany on the 22nd.
> 2. I went to Texas Park on the 1st.